# How to simplify this code using newtonsoft or other json parsers?

Tags: json, vb.net, linq, parsing

I got a simple json

```
{"200567175963759": {  "pair": "esp_btc",  "type": "sell",  "amount": 2000000,  "rate": 1E-08,  "timestamp_created": "1498114417",  "status": 0}}
```

I want to parse it without creating any new classes. I want to make it easy.

I am using jsonhelper class that I created my self to parse it. It's basically try to find the first thing between two double quotes and got 200567175963759 which is the order id. Get parameter is simply finding something between "pair":"  and "

For simple json it works fine. How can I do get order ID, which si 200567175963759, or timestamp, using better parser, like newtonsoft.

I wonder if I can do that using newtonsoft json?

```
                Dim jsonstring = jsonHelper.stripWhiteSpace(order3.ToString) '{"200567175963759": {  "pair": "esp_btc",  "type": "sell",  "amount": 2000000,  "rate": 1E-08,  "timestamp_created": "1498114417",  "status": 0}}
                Dim orderid = fGetToken(order3.ToString, 1, """", """")
                Dim base = b
                Dim quote = key
                Dim typeOfOrder = jsonHelper.getParameter(jsonstring, "type")
                Dim amount = jsonHelper.getParameter(jsonstring, "amount")
                Dim rate = jsonHelper.getParameter(jsonstring, "rate")
                Dim timestamp_created = jsonHelper.getParameter(jsonstring, "timestamp_created")
                Dim order4 = OrdersAtExchange.createOrders(amount, base, quote, _exchange, timestamp_created, rate, orderid)
                _orders.Add(order4)
```

If I try to parse that using newtonsoft, I got this object whose type is

```
            Dim order = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonorders)
            Dim order1 = CType(order, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)
            Dim order2 = order1.Item("return").ToList
```

I look at all the method in Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject I can't find anything that say convert dictionary structures in json to say generic.dictionary

There is something like that. I tried but simply didn't work.

So I wonder if there's an actual sample of some code parsing that simple json with newtonsoft?

Answer (score 1):

Object is Type Dictionary, In case if property looks like index or key it probably dictionary

```
    Dim JsonString As String = "{""200567175963759"": {  ""pair"": ""esp_btc"",  ""type"": ""sell"",  ""amount"": 2000000,  ""rate"": 1E-08,  ""timestamp_created"": ""1498114417"",  ""status"": 0}}"
    Dim JsonSettings = New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
    JsonSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore
    Dim OutObject =  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, SampleType))(JsonString)

Class SampleType
  Property pair As String
  Property type As String
  Property amount As String
  Property rate As String
Property timestamp_created As String
Property status As String
End Class
```

Comment: I don't want to use classes. I think I can do that with Jtoken Jobject and Jarray

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample showing how you can parse your JSON using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API (JTokens, JObjects, etc.)

```
Dim json As String =
    "{" &
    "  ""200567175963759"": {" &
    "    ""pair"": ""esp_btc""," &
    "    ""type"": ""sell""," &
    "    ""amount"": 2000000," &
    "    ""rate"": 1E-08," &
    "    ""timestamp_created"": ""1498114417""," &
    "    ""status"": 0" &
    "  }" &
    "}"

Dim rootObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

For Each prop As JProperty In rootObject.Properties()

    Dim orderid As String = prop.Name
    Dim orderInfo As JObject = prop.Value
    Dim pair As String = orderInfo("pair").ToString()
    Dim typeOfOrder As String = orderInfo("type").ToString()
    Dim amount As Decimal = orderInfo("amount").ToObject(Of Decimal)
    Dim rate As Decimal = orderInfo("rate").ToObject(Of Decimal)
    Dim timestamp_created As String = orderInfo("timestamp_created").ToString()
    Dim status As Integer = orderInfo("status").ToObject(Of Integer)

    'etc. ...

Next
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/X9SPIE