# VB.Net Getting Value from JSON

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, javascriptserializer

Please could someone help me get the branch_id in each branch from this JSON?

```
{
    "branches": {
        "1": {
            "member_id": "-16",
            "branch_id": "1"
        },
        "2": {
            "member_id": "-16",
            "branch_id": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using JavaScriptSerialiser to deserialize the JSON but am not doing it properly as I think the JSON is not an array like I have used before:

```
 Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim data As OfficeCheckJsonResponse = jss.Deserialize(Of OfficeCheckJsonResponse)(responseFromServer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a `Branch` class and add a property `branches As Dictionary(Of String, Branch)` to your `OfficeCheckJsonResponse` class.

Using JavaScriptSerialiser, deserialise the JSON into an instance of `OfficeCheckJsonResponse`.

You can get your `branch_id` values by iterating over `data.branches`. You could alternatively use LINQ.

```
Sub Main
    Dim responseFromServer = "{
    ""branches"":  {
        ""1"": {
            ""member_id"": ""-16"",
            ""branch_id"": ""1""
        },
        ""2"": {
            ""member_id"": ""-16"",
            ""branch_id"": ""1""
        }
    }
}"

    Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim data As OfficeCheckJsonResponse =
        jss.Deserialize(Of OfficeCheckJsonResponse)(responseFromServer)

    For Each branch As KeyValuePair(Of String, Branch) In data.branches
        Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(branch.Key))
        Console.WriteLine(branch.Value)
    Next
End Sub

Public Class OfficeCheckJsonResponse
    Public Property branches As Dictionary(Of String, Branch)
End Class

Public Class Branch
    Property member_id As String
    Property branch_id As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Newtonsoft, object type is dictionary(of integer, SampleClass) like in this same topic, check link
[Go This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904824/how-to-simplify-this-code-using-newtonsoft-or-other-json-parsers/46909863#46909863)

```
    Dim JsonSettings = New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
    JsonSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore
    Dim OutObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of branch)("###JSONSTRING###")
    Public Class branch
        Property branches As Dictionary(Of Integer, SampleClass)
        Class SampleClass
            Property member_id As String
            Property branch_id As String
        End Class
    End Class
```

Class is inside Value property and Key is Unique String like in this case 1,2,3,4 ...

```
         For Each DictionaryElement As KeyValuePair(Of String, BranchesData) In branches
            Debug.Print(DictionaryElement.Key) 'Is Key 1,2,3 etc..
            'DictionaryElement.Value is BranchesData
            Debug.Print(DictionaryElement.Value.branch_id)
            Debug.Print(DictionaryElement.Value.member_id)
        Next
```

Comment: Hi Norbert.  Thank you.  I have used your suggestion and managed to get the data deserialized but cannot get to iterate..  I have amended my initial message above to show.  Would you be able to suggest what I do to get to the branch_id and member_id?

Comment: Overthinking it..  just looping through For x = 1 To data.branches.Count and getting the values..  Thank you for your wisdom and assistance..